# Bootstrap row height in xs grid when using offcanvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jsfiddle

I find that when I decrease the width of my browser to match the dimensions of a mobile screen,the `div` containing the `row-offcanvas` and another `row` that has the content has a really small width with a scrollbar.

This is a [fiddle with my code](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/71mokucn/)

This is my html:

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fargo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <!--Add stuff here-->
        </div>          
    </div>      
</nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <div id="sidebar" role="navigation" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 sidebar-offcanvas">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="text-primary">Panel 1</span>
                            <a href="#p1" class="accordion-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#p1" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="p1" class="collapse panel-collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                There is a table of details to be placed here
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="text-primary">Panel 1</span>
                            <a href="#p2" class="accordion-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#p2" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="p2" class="collapse panel-collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                There is a table of details to be placed here
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="text-primary">Panel 1</span>
                            <a href="#p3" class="accordion-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#p3" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="p3" class="collapse panel-collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                There is a table of details to be placed here
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                <div class="visible-xs">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                        Toggle Menu
                    </button>
                </div>
                content
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

This is my css:

```
 body{
    padding-top:60px;   
}
#sidebar
{
    height:100%;
}
```

## UPDATE:

I changed to `navbar-static-top` and added a `height` of `100%` to `body` and `sidebar`.
I changed to `col-xs-12` instead of `col-xs-4` for `#sidebar`.
I still find that at mobile width,the container does not occupy the height of the window(except for what has been taken),is it because the content is also within the same row.

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/71mokucn/4/) with all these changes factored in.

## UPDATE2:

I moved the main page content to another `container` `div` hopeful of solving the issue but the same problem continues to plauge me.

[This is an updated fiddle to reflect this](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/1s1epyjy/)

Comment: Actually in fiddle its not working properly! try it in your own solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <div style="margin-top:50px" class="container">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <div id="sidebar" role="navigation" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 sidebar-offcanvas">
```

Use `col-xs-12` for mobile view

Comment: I found that the `navbar-static-fixed` is still overlapping with the `container`.I stripped it down further,removed the `container`,changed to `col-xs-12` and  changed to `navbar-static-top` but the problem still persists,[here is a fiddle with all the changes](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/71mokucn/2/)

Comment: yes i saw that for that you should use `margin-top` for the container which is placed next to the navbar

Comment: see my updated post, Hope my post will solve your issue

Comment: I see that when you add `margin-top` and then add `height:100%` to both `container` and `body`,I still find that at mobile width,the `container` does not occupy the height of the `window`(except for what has been taken),is it because the content is also within the same row,[here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/71mokucn/4/)

Comment: I have tried to move the main page content to a seperate `container` with it's own `row`.This yields no difference.[Here is an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/1s1epyjy/)

Comment: In fiddle its not suppoting bootstrap styles properly http://jsfiddle.net/1s1epyjy/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59840/discussion-between-user2309862-and-jake745).